# Perl HTML::Treebuilder::Xpath not able to find child tags

Tags: perl, xpath

HTML Structure is,

```
<div class="profile-content"><section class="content-section"><h3 class="subheader">Welcome to the party</h3>
```

I want to print

> Welcome to the party

Code is as below,

```
my $profile= $tree->findvalue('//div[@class="profile-content"]/section[@class="content-section"]/h3[@class="subheader"]');
```

But it is not printing anything.

Please help me.

Regards

Comment: The xpath looks correct. Please [edit] your question and add the full Perl code you are using, including the printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<section>` is an HTML5 tag, which is not recognized by HTML::TreeBuilder. By default it is not present in the internal representation of the HTML.

Setting the `ignore_unknown` option to 0 (false) should give you what you want.

See the difference:

```
> perl -MHTML::TreeBuilder -E'my $t=HTML::TreeBuilder->new; $t->parse( q{<div class="profile-content"><section class="content-section"><h3 class="subheader">Welcome to the party</h3>}); say $t->as_HTML'
<html><head></head><body><div class="profile-content"><h3 class="subheader">Welcome to the party</h3></div></body></html>

> perl -MHTML::TreeBuilder -E'my $t=HTML::TreeBuilder->new; $t->ignore_unknown( 0); $t->parse( q{<div class="profile-content"><section class="content-section"><h3 class="subheader">Welcome to the party</h3>}); print $t->as_HTML'
<html><head></head><body><div class="profile-content"><section class="content-section"><h3 class="subheader">Welcome to the party</h3></section></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It solved my issue.